# Calculating CSS positioning of small divs around another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is more in the realm of "is this possible without a stupid amount of code?" and to get some ideas of how to go about it.  If I had a css representation of a dinner table, and wanted to position 4-10 chairs around it, I might create the divs like this (inline to show what I'm doing compactly)

```
<div style="position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;">
<div id="table" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="chair1" style="position:absolute;width:10px;height:10px;">&nbsp;    </div>
<div id="chair2" style="position:absolute;width:10px;height:10px;">&nbsp;    </div>
<div id="chair3" style="position:absolute;width:10px;height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="chair4" style="position:absolute;width:10px;height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Where there's a div to hold it all and a div to represent 4 chairs and a table.  But what if my dynamically created code needed to create 6, 8, or 10 chairs?  How would I go about spacing them dynamically off the table at an even rate around the table?  Thoughts?

Comment: To me, the simplest flexible solution to this would be absolute positioning using JS for the calculations. But if that's not on the table *cough*...

Comment: Welcome to SO! "Thoughts?"/"Is this possible"-type questions are good to talk about with people but not really what SO is for. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on writing SO questions

Comment: My apologies.  Wasn't aware the posting was so focused. I will take it to heart next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript in order to set the chairs. Something to get you started:

HTML:

```
<div id="room">
  <div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#room {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
#table {
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.chair {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
var $chair = $('<div class="chair">');
var $room = $('#room');
var top = 0;
var left = 0;
var stepSize = 20;

var createChairs = function(amount) {
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
     var newChair = $chair.clone();
     newChair.css({top: top, left: left});
     $room.append(newChair);
     left = left + stepSize;
  }
}

createChairs(10);
```

You create a function which you pass the amount of chairs you wish, then you go around the border and set as much chairs as wished. This example does not include the border handling yet i.e. it will just set chairs from the top left to the top right. But handling borders should be easy doable with a few conditions. You should have gotten the idea.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0oady2q/

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how you would be able to do this without at least a little bit of JavaScript.  In fact, even if you tried to use some kind of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) magic, you would still run into the issue that `calc()` doesn't support `sin()` or `cos()` calls.

Here is a small, pure JavaScript way to get what you want though:

```js
/*jslint browser:true*/

(function(doc) {
  "use strict";

  var TABLE_RADIUS = 100;

  function each(arr, cb) {
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, cb);
  }

  function deg2rad(deg) {
    return ((deg * Math.PI) / 180);
  }

  function pos(deg, r) {
    return {
      x: (r * (Math.cos(deg2rad(deg)))),
      y: (r * (Math.sin(deg2rad(deg))))
    };
  }

  function chairIterator(chair, chairIndex, chairArr) {
    var circPos = pos(chairIndex / chairArr.length * 360, TABLE_RADIUS);
    chair.style.top = circPos.y + "px";
    chair.style.left = circPos.x + "px";
  }

  function tableIterator(table) {
    var chairs = table.querySelectorAll(".chair");
    each(chairs, chairIterator);
  }

  function main() {
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
    each(tables, tableIterator);
  }

  doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
}(document));
```

```css
.table {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.table .chair {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
  <div class="chair"></div>
</div>
```